# Access Local sub domain with IP in wamp

Tags: subdomain, wamp

### What I need is as follows

I am able to access the sub domain in my local machine as follows `test.localhost` but I need `test.myMachineName` or `test.myMachineIp` to access from another computer in my own network

I have setup the sub domain in my local wamp server as follows:

**IN https-vhost.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias test.localhost
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

### And then enabled vhost in httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

### Then added in windows host as follows

```
127.0.0.1       test.localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your configuration. First, if you access test.localhost from another computer will not work because your website does not exist on that computer. You have to use the IP address and port forwarding in your router settings (Private IP: Computer local IP, Type: TCP, Range: 80 - 80).

In **https-vhost.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test"
    ServerName test.youripaddress
    ServerAlias test.youripaddress
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

In **HOST** file:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
youripaddress       test.youripaddress
```

Ask me any questions.

Comment: working fine int the same computer where wamp is, but its not working in another computer in the same network

Comment: Did you do port forwarding? youripaddress = your router ip address = that appearing on sites like http://myipaddress.com/. Did you use that IP?

Comment: couldn't get you ... I am able to access my ip on another machine ex 198.168.120.120 in another machine but not able to access test.198.168.120.120 (I am not like to use the public ip for this purpose)

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Unfortunately, I think you can not do this without you own a domain. I do not think you can access an IP subdomain. Let me know if you find any solution. More information http://serverfault.com/questions/162710/how-to-access-a-subdomain-of-an-ip-address

Comment: Did you add `test.198.168.120.120` to the hosts file of the other machine? You can simulate a DNS controller if you are willing to manually edit and maintain hosts files (this is not fun).

Comment: @DragosSandu +1 for your effort